# Finding parcels which combine to create largest area

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, polygon, area, dissolve

I have a shapefile of 500 polygons and I need to find the 22 neighboring polygons that when combined will produce the largest continuous area.

Does this involve the Dissolve tool?

What do I dissolve the polygons by in order to get the largest area?

Comment: Could you explain what it means to "combine" polygons? This may be a difficult packing problem, depending on what you mean.